# Same distance among breaks in a year variable for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, scale

I have a dataframe with years and a numeric variable

```
df <- data.frame(years = c(1, 500, 1000, seq(1100, 2000, 100)),
                 numbers = sample(13))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = years, y = numbers)) +
  geom_line()
```

How could I see in the x axis the same distance between each ordered break? For instance, year 1 and year 500 should have the same distance in the plot than year 1500 and year 1600.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? An inconsistent scale on the x axis add cognitive load to the plot reader.

Answer (score 3):

You can plot the years as a factor:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(years), y = numbers, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "years")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
plot(numbers ~ years, df, 'l')
```

-output

[image]